# Every module of finite uniform dimension is a direct sum of (finitely many) indecomposable

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (commutative or non-commutative, associative, unital) ring. It is very well known that any artinian or noetherian $R$-module $M$ is a direct sum of (finitely many) indecomposable submodules. Some months ago, I just happened to note that the result generalizes to the case where $M$ has finite [uniform dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_module) (by Corollary (6.7)(1) in Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings*, every artinian or noetherian module has finite uniform dimension). However, I haven't yet been able to find a reference for this generalization; and that's precisely what I'm hoping for with this question.

It's obvious to me that the result is nothing new. But I'm surprised that I can't see it mentioned in any of the standard books (maybe because it's commonly stated in a more general form).

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401039/.